# Issue with Semantic Segmentation Model Predictions: Loss and IOU Score Look Good, but Predictions are Distorted

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I'm working on a semantic segmentation task where I need to predict defects on the surfaces of materials. I trained a model using a UNet from the segmentation-models library. After training for 100 epochs, here are the results:

- Loss: 0.050262
- Mean IOU Score: 0.89968

However, when I try to make predictions on an image, the result appears distorted. The defect's position is correct, but the shape is completely wrong. I'm not sure if this issue is related to how I'm plotting the image or if it's a problem with the model itself.

Here's a snippet of my code:

MODEL

```
# Create the segmentation model
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, classes=1, input_shape=(320, 320, 3), activation='sigmoid')

# Display model summary
print(model.summary())

# Define optimizer
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

# Define loss functions and metrics
dice_loss = sm.losses.DiceLoss() 
binary_crossentropy = sm.losses.binary_crossentropy
metrics = [sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5)]

# Compile the Keras model with the defined optimizer, loss, and metrics
model.compile(optim, binary_crossentropy, metrics)

# Other code related to data loading and preprocessing

# Train the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_dataloader, 
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataloader)//BATCH_SIZE, 
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    callbacks=callbacks, 
    validation_data=valid_dataloader, 
    validation_steps=len(valid_dataloader)//BATCH_SIZE,
)
```

plotting predictions:

```
# Load a test image and its ground truth mask
print(test_img_number)
image, gt_mask = test_dataset[295]

# Prepare the test image for prediction
test_img_pre = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
print(test_img_pre.shape)

# Make predictions using the model
prediction = (model.predict(test_img_pre)[0, :, :, 0] > 0.2).astype(np.uint8)

# Visualize the results
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.subplot(231)
plt.title('Testing Image')
plt.imshow(image[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(232)
plt.title('Testing Label')
plt.imshow(gt_mask[:, :], cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(233)
plt.title('Prediction on Test Image')
plt.imshow(prediction, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

Here is one example of output:

[image: Output]

And if I delete from this line:

```
prediction = (model.predict(test_img_pre)[0, :, :, 0] > 0.2).astype(np.uint8)
```

the part "> 0.2).astype(np.uint8)" results are even worse. I also don't know if 0.2 would be a good value for all the images of the test set.

[image: output2]

I would appreciate any guidance on why my predictions might be distorted and how to troubleshoot this issue. Thank you!